# How can I fix my media queries not responding for mobile device display (across all platforms)?

Tags: html, css

This a homework assignment. I need to take the existing code for a website I already made, and make it compatible with mobile device viewing. They want me to do this by adding responsive design elements. Currently, the desktop website is a two-column format. For mobile display, the website is supposed to be converted into a single-column format. When I open my website my phone, the website is still displayed as a two-column layout.

I've checked everything with CSS and HTML validators. No errors were detected. I followed the book instructions step by step, and have to include everything they tell me to include, but for some reason, it is still not showing up correctly on mobile devices. (I also tested to see if the issue was and iPhone or android problem only. Both devices don't display the website properly).

The first sample of code is the code for the HTML to show I did use a meta tag in the head. And the second sample of code is my external CSS that has the media queries.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title> Fish Creek Animal Clinic </title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="fishcreek.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header>
                <h1> Fish Creek Animal Clinic </h1>
            </header>
            <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html"> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.html"> Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="askvet.html"> Ask The Vet</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html"> Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
            <main>
                <dl>
                    <dt>Full Service Facility</dt>
                    <dd>Doctors and staff are on duty 24 hours a day, 7 days a week.<dd>
                    <dt>Years of Experience</dt>
                    <dd>Fish Creek Veterinarians have provided quality, dependable care for your beloved animals since 1984.</dd>
                    <dt>Open Door Policy</dt>
                    <dd>Our professionals welcome owners to stay with their pets during any medical procedure.</dd>
                </dl>
                <div>
                    <a id="mobile" href="tel:800-555-5555">800-555-5555</a><br> 
                    <span id="desktop">800-555-5555</span><br>
                    1242 Grassy Lane<br>
                    Fish Creek, WI 55534<br><br>
                </div>
            </main>
            <footer>
                Copyright &copy; 2018 Fish Creek Animal Clinic. All Rights Reserved.<br>
                <a href="mailto:jescobedo3@saddleback.edu"> jescobedo3@saddleback.edu </a>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    body {margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: white;
        background-image: none;
    }

    #wrapper {
        width: auto;
        min-width: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    h1 {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 1.8em;
        line-height: 200%;
    }

    nav {
        float: none;
        padding: 0;
        width: auto;
    }

    nav li {display: inline-block;}

    nav a {
        padding: 1em;
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }

    nav ul {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    main {
        font-size: 90%;
        margin: 0;
        padding-left: 2em;
    }

    footer {margin: 0;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    header {background-image: url(lilfish.gif)}

    h1 {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        line-height: 120%;
    }

    nav a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0.2em;
        font-size: 1em;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #330000;
    }

    nav li {display: block;}

    nav ul {text-align: left;}

    main {padding-left: 1em;}

    .category {text-shadow: none;}

    #mobile {display: inline;}

    #desktop {display: none;}
}
```

Comment: firstly, you will need to share your HTML code for someone to help you. Secondly, can you use bootstrap css?

Comment: I'm not really seeing rules that create a two-column layout - what are the columns supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use media queries for different sizes and also according to devices orientation also.

```
<style>
     /* For Device Size */

/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {  

   /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

}

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {  

   /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

}

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {  

   /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

} 

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {  

   /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

}      

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {

   /* Your CSS Code for this device size */ 

}

     /* For Device Orientation */
/* According to Mobile Orientation */
@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {   

   /* Your CSS Code for this device orientation */    

}

</style>
```